# clock() is not letting me store in a clock_t variable

Tags: c, time, microcontroller

I am writing some code for a *C2000 microcontroller*, and I am trying to time certain segments of my code using `time.h`. However, when i enter this code:

```
clock_t begin = clock();
```

It sends back a bunch of errors.  Including one that says: `error: function call is not allowed in a constant expression`.  But I don't believe it is a constant expression.

Does anyone have an idea what might be going on here?

Further errors include:

> --output_all_syms --cdebug_asm_data --preproc_with_compile -- preproc_dependency="Example_2802xAdcTempSensor.pp"  "../Example_2802xAdcTempSensor.c"
>       "../Example_2802xAdcTempSensor.c", line 155: error: expected a "}"
>       clock_t start = clock();
>
> "../Example_2802xAdcTempSensor.c", line 155: error: function call is not
>             allowed in a constant expression
>     clock_t start = clock();
>                     ^

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show us the exact code ?

Comment: That's a strange error.

Comment: The rest of the "bunch of errors" might be important. Especially if the one you've chosen to share with us isn't the first one.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley Ok I'll add some more.

Comment: @Eman No need to hide it. ;-)

Comment: am suspecting there's a missing `;` in a previous line, a missing `}`, or some such...

Comment: @Floris That's why Eman disappeared… he just found it. ;-)

Comment: @BitFiddlingCodeMonkey Nope still no luck.

Comment: `line 155: error: expected a "}"` AHA! I was right… Show more code. The error is not what you think. There is a hanging open-bracket somewhere.

Comment: @Floris one of the errors that I just added does say that that it expected a "}" as you can see above.  But I fail to see how or why.

Comment: So show us lines 1 through 156 (at a minimum) and we'll cast our beady eyes on it.

Comment: @Floris You're right it seems to be something else.  Let me poke around a  little and I'll see if I can figure out what.

Comment: Yes, let us steal you awesome code! ;-)

Comment: @Floris It looks like what it was, is that I was defining the variable inside `main()`.  Once I moved it outside it worked fine.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: That's peculiar; can you make a **short** program that reproduces the error (and show how to make it go away)? If you did that as an answer I would definitely give it a +1!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the definition just had to be moved outside of the main loop.  Once I did this it worked fine.

Comment: This is really weird. Can you reduce the code to show an example of it failing? Also what compiler/platform are you using?

Answer (score 4):

Split it into two lines:

```
clock_t begin;
begin = clock();
```

The compiler wants the initialization to be a constant expression (per the error message) - which a function call is not.

By splitting it like this you are saying "when the program is running and gets to this point, that is the time I want to evaluate this function". And all will be well.

Comment: I have tried this and it still doesn't work

Comment: It says that `begin = clock();` is not compatible with `clock_t begin;`

Comment: Can you show complete code (`#include`s, compile directives, ...) of the smallest program that has this error (probably just a dozen lines max) - and then show the complete error listing as well?

Comment: Did you `#include <time.h>` ?

Comment: Yes i did include `<time.h>`

Comment: Is `begin` `const` somehow?